# Sesame alibaba mapping subclasses

Tags: mapping, subclass, rdf, sesame

I'm programming an application Web (Semantic Web) and for storing the triples, using sesame, and for mapping of data alibaba. My question is, that way I have to implement the classes,to that at the base of triplets is store an object as a subclass of another , try interfaces but I got no results , below I present the "entities":

the parent class:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.openrdf.annotations.Iri;

@Iri(Parent.NS + "Parent")
public interface Parent {
    public static final String NS = "http://www.spelta.ec/ontology/example#";

    @Iri(Parent.NS +"code")
    BigInteger getCode();

    @Iri(Parent.NS +"code")
    void setCode(BigInteger code);

    @Iri(Parent.NS+"description")
    String getDescription();

    @Iri(Parent.NS+"description")
    void setDescription(String description);

}
```

The child class:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Child implements Parent {

    private BigInteger code;

    private String description;

    @Override
    public BigInteger getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCode(BigInteger code) {
       this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

to consult the store of triples, should define an instance of the Children class is a subclass of Parent

many thanks